# How to have the Label in the middle left of the Radio block

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.leftRadio {
    display:inline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <label >  The Label   </label>
   <div class="leftRadio">
      <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Male
      <br>
      <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Female
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to have the label in the middle left of the Radio block
how to use the css and class to get it.

Comment: Do you have any css?

Comment: I write one simple, but can't locate the lable in the left of the whole Radio part.
<style>
 .leftRadio {
  display:inline;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <label >  The Label   </label>
   <div class="leftRadio">
     <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Male
  <br>
     <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Female
   </div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: Are you able to link a picture of what you want?

Comment: no, i can't paste the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use flexbox, this will put them all on the same line, I would recommend reading up on using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**css**

```
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#leftRadio {
  display: flex;
}
```

**html**

```
 <div id="container">
   <label >  The Label   </label>
   <div id="leftRadio">
      <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Male
      <br>
      <input  type="radio" name="sex"  /> Female
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I got what I want. I will learn Flex more~